# Access Form Authenticated PDF files from different Project (ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net, authentication, pdf, forms-authentication

I have a asp.Net Website where we have implemented Forms Authentication.By using it PDF files in particular folder are accessible only to Authenticated users (Form Authentication).

I have another Website which provides links to user to download PDF files from above mentioned project (Note that this project too uses its own Form authentication).

But currently I am not able to access PDF files of first project via second project, So Can any one help me about how to access these form authenticated files from different Project.

Comment: when the second project is trying to access the pdf file , can you not impersonate the user(assuming currently authenticated user need access to a pdf) as some predefined user who has access to the pdf file?  Why do you need to access the pdf file through first project and not directly to the file itself?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is in the next question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554436/cross-domain-cookies-with-formsauthentication

Comment: @FernandoGutierrez..this is very near what i want and can be accepted.so please put it as answer so that it can be accepted.